# Hover animation making website horizontal scrollable

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

so the hover animation causes my website to be scrolled horizontally. How do I fix this while also maintaining the same hover animation effect?

If I remove the hover animation, the website can't be scrolled horizontally. The hover animation basically show another text after hovering over one. It decreases the opacity of the original text while bring in the second text from the right side.

Hover animation css:

```
 .project-title-right span {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.project-title-right:before,
.project-title-right:after {
    color: #B52830;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
}

.project-title-right:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:after {
    content: attr(data-active);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:hover span,
.project-title-right:active span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.project-title-right:hover:before,
.project-tile:active:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.project-title-right:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Hover implementation:

```
<h2 class="project-title-right" data-hover="Interactive Site" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="700" data-aos-offset="150"><span>Evolution of Computer Science</span></h2>
```

```css
.device-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.center-y {
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.square-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 30px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% + 200px);
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: #3e82ef;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.width-l {
    max-width: 800px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 87.5vw;
}

.padding-l {
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}


.grid-2 {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}
    
/*Hover Animation*/
.project-title-right span {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.project-title-right:before,
.project-title-right:after {
    color: #B52830;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
}

.project-title-right:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:after {
    content: attr(data-active);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:hover span,
.project-title-right:active span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.project-title-right:hover:before,
.project-tile:active:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.project-title-right:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid-2 padding-l">
            <div>
                <div class="device-container">
                    <div class="square-left"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex center-y">
                <div class="width-l">
                    <h2 class="project-title-right" data-hover="Interactive Site" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="700" data-aos-offset="150"><span>Evolution of Computer Science</span></h2>
                    <p class="blocksize color-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel ei dico oratio malorum. Id pri agam oratio. Partem labores ullamcorper est no. At vivendum facilisis conceptam vis, iusto accumsan erroribus pri id. Id eum nominati liberavisse, dolorum persecuti ea
                        his, pri et everti definitionem.</p>
                    <a class="cta color-deepblue" href="about">Learn more ›</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: There isn't nearly enough code here to figure out what's going on. At a guess, I'd say to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the body

Comment: Thats the only code that goes into the hover animation. Removing this part of code will fix the situation. However, I want to still have the hover animation. Adding overflow-x: hidden to body will only remove the scroll, it won't prevent user from scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS you're using, in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use the [**Stack Snippets**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) feature to help you out.

Comment: @DanielSixl I just added a snippet to my question. Can you please take a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. Now we have a context to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your pseudo element:

```
.project-title-right:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
}
```

With the transform `translate(150%, 0)` used, it occupies additional space. You will need to control the overflow behaviour of a parent element. You could add an `overflow: hidden;` to your container.

```css
.device-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.center-y {
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.square-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 30px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% + 200px);
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: #3e82ef;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.width-l {
    max-width: 800px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 87.5vw;
    overflow: hidden; /* added as an example */
}

.padding-l {
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}


.grid-2 {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}
    
/*Hover Animation*/
.project-title-right span {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.project-title-right:before,
.project-title-right:after {
    color: #B52830;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
    transition: .4s, opacity .6s;
}

.project-title-right:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:after {
    content: attr(data-active);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}

.project-title-right:hover span,
.project-title-right:active span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.project-title-right:hover:before,
.project-tile:active:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.project-title-right:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0);
    transform: translate(150%, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid-2 padding-l">
            <div>
                <div class="device-container">
                    <div class="square-left"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex center-y">
                <div class="width-l">
                    <h2 class="project-title-right" data-hover="Interactive Site" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="700" data-aos-offset="150"><span>Evolution of Computer Science</span></h2>
                    <p class="blocksize color-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel ei dico oratio malorum. Id pri agam oratio. Partem labores ullamcorper est no. At vivendum facilisis conceptam vis, iusto accumsan erroribus pri id. Id eum nominati liberavisse, dolorum persecuti ea
                        his, pri et everti definitionem.</p>
                    <a class="cta color-deepblue" href="about">Learn more ›</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.